# How to define a map iterator in c++ using map name and printing map<int.class>

Tags: c++

Firstly, can I declare a map iterator for the following class

```
class obj {
public:
    map<int,double> m1;
};

map<int,obj> m;
```

as `m::iterator it = m.begin();` or should I it declare as `map<int,obj>::iterator it = m.begin();`

Secondly, I want to print the map `m`.
How can I print the above given map that has its value data type as class and that class contains another map?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use this handy little feature called `auto`. It can be used in place of types in some context, like when declaring a variable.

In your code, it would look like this:

```
struct obj {
    map<int,double> m1;
};

map<int,obj> m;

// Here! The compiler will replace the `auto` placeholder by `map<int,obj>::iterator`
auto it = m.begin();
```

If you really want to write that down this `::iterator` member of `m`, you can use `decltype`:

```
// Here! The compiler will replace the `decltype(m)` placeholder by `map<int,obj>`
decltype(m)::iterator it = m.begin();
```

---

As for the second part of the question, simply two range for loop will do the job:

```
for (auto&& [key1, value1] : m) {
    std::cout << key1;

    for (auto&& [key2, value2] : value1.m1) {
        std::cout << key2 << value2;
    }
}
```

This code above will output all data of the map in one line, without spaces.

The code above uses `auto&&`. It's pretty much like `auto`, but it will deduce  types as references.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators can be declared as -
`std::map<int, obj>iterator it = m.begin()`

To print them -

```
for (std::map<int, obj>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first;
    for (std::map<int, double>::iterator it1 = it->second.m1.begin(); it1 != it->second.m1.end(); ++it1) {
        std::cout << it1->first << it1->second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.But my problem is map is defined in a class in one file and i am printing it in other file by passing the object of the class to the print function.          Can't i declare the iterator just by using the map name like m::iterator it=m.begin();

Comment: Try using `auto` as @Guillaume suggested